# Easy way to include screenshots in PRs via githubs `gh` CLI?

Tags: github

I write PRs on a daily basis. Lately I've been using the GitHub CLI to do things like `gh pr create` on the command line and then write the body in my favorite editor.

Sadly, I almost always want to include a screenshot. In the browser it's drag-and-drop to both upload the image to GitHub's servers and insert the markdown with the resulting URL. I'd love a hands-on-keyboard flow for this, so I can finish my PR without jumping over to the browser or leaving the terminal. Anyone know of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/4745) it won't be implemented, and won't be a feature for cli for a longer time just like how S3 presigned url isn't very sofisticated on the cli. The browser has a lot of builtins and features which allows it to be a browser driven feature.

The [AwS sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) is open source and you're welcome to contribute and add that in, and perhaps Microsoft can also pick it up on their side also.

If you want to know more about the technical challenges around this or find out more as to why this isn't prioritised for cli check out [these slides](https://fth.link/presign)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).